# The performance_schema database of MySQL has been deleted by mistake. Is there any way to recover it?

Tags: mysql-8.0

Yesterday I dealt with a production data problem for them. I used Navicat during operation. I didn’t know how to press the backspace key. Because it is a Mac system, this backspace key was deleted. I have used Mac). I was in a depressed mood at the time. I didn’t notice that this database was selected. The result was confirmed. Later, I deleted a table from another database. Then today, the production database cannot be connected, so I knew it was Yesterday, I deleted the library. I want to ask the boss if there is any way? The MySQL version is 8.0.11 and there is currently a binlog log, but I don't know how to restore it.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Command Prompt and run the following:

```
mysql_upgrade --user=root --password=password --force
```

Restart the MySQL.

You should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, but it dosn't work. :(